# get multiple values from dropdownlist in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-select

How can I get the values selected in the drop-down list, using a JavaScript function?  User can select multiple values from both the  elements.  Following are the  elements I'm using.  Thanks in advance.

```
<select name="icOptions" id="icOptions" style="display: none" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="Choose an Option" selected="selected">Choose a Team </option>
  <option value="IDX">IDX</option>
  <option value="Support">SUPPORT</option>
  <option value="webapps">WEBAPPS</option>
</select>

<select name="ocOptions" id="ocOptions" style="display: none" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="Choose an Option" selected="selected">Choose a TeamMember </option>
  <option value="sanjay740">sanjay740</option>
  <option value="milind740">milind740</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
var fld = document.getElementById('icOptions');
var values = [];
for (var i = 0; i < fld.options.length; i++) {
  if (fld.options[i].selected) {
    values.push(fld.options[i].value);
  }
}
// do something with values
```

Comment: Thanx it worked with little modification. alert('you selected' + fld.options[i].value); because i wanted selected values. well Thanx again

Answer (score 0):

Really Awesome Library for your need using jQuery or Prototype
http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/
Have a look at it.

It supports select & multiselect in a really nice way

Answer (score 0):

An ES6/functional style alternative to the accepted answer:

```
const values = Array.apply(null, e.target.options)
  .filter(option => option.selected)
  .map(option => option.value);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it's usually better to provide an explanation of why and how this code helps in this case. See [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)